# Node.js // A module to manage a sqlite database

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-modules

I managed to create a module to handle all the database call. It uses this lib: https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3

My issues are the following.
Everytime I make a call, I need to make sure the database exist, and if not to create it.
Plus, as all the calls are asynchronous, I end up having loads of functions in functions in callbacks ... etc.

It pretty much looks like this:

```
getUsers : function (callback){
    var _aUsers = [];
    var that = this;
    this._setupDb(function(){
        var db = that.db;

        db.all("SELECT * FROM t_client", function(err, rows) {
            rows.forEach(function (row) {
                _aUsers.push({"cli_id":row.id,"cli_name":row.cli_name,"cli_path":row.cli_path});

            });
            callback(_aUsers);
        });
    });
},
```

So, is there any way I can export my module only when the database is ready and fully created if it does not exist yet?

Does anyone see a way around the "asynchronous" issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. If you make it synchronous, you are taking away the advantage. Javascript functions are meant to be that way. Such a situation is referred to as [callback hell](https://coderwall.com/p/ineqig). If you are facing problems managing callbacks then you can use these libraries :

- [underscore](https://npmjs.org/package/underscore)
- [async](https://npmjs.org/package/async)

See these guides to understand basics of asynchronous programming

- [Node.js: Style and structure](http://caolanmcmahon.com/posts/nodejs_style_and_structure/)
- Using underscore.js [managing-callback-spaghetti-in-nodejs](http://whaleventures.blogspot.in/2012/02/managing-callback-spaghetti-in-nodejs.html)
- Using async.js [node-js-async-programming](http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-async-programming.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using [promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or [fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) ...

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look into this !